# Empty RSS Feeds

Tags: rss, feed

When i try to access feeds for tags,categories and authors, i get empty list. If i try to open feeds for the site, i get "Page not found"

**Empty Feed:**

http://thinkzarahatke.com/category/advertisement/video/feed

http://thinkzarahatke.com/author/amty/feed

**Page not Found :**

http://thinkzarahatke.com/feed

I had tried fix rss feed plugin. But it dint solved my problem too. Please help.

Comment: Try revert to default theme (Twenty Ten) and see whether the problem still there. Make sure you hard-refresh your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Zeo suggestion, i activated default wordpress theme (Twenty Ten) -> I opened feeds then -> it was getting opened properly. I again to switched my theme without any changes. And it started working.

If someone knows then please reason behind this.

Comment: There can be many things that cause this, it's hard to know without looking at your specific installation. I would just mark your own answer as the accepted answer so that system knows it is solved for you.

Answer (score 1):

Technically your feeds are not empty, but contain no items. This probably means that query for those items fail for some reason, but (between theme and plugins) it is hard to guess why.

Generic approach to debugging this would start with disabling plugins, switching to default theme and [enabling `WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug).